# How to upgrade to symfony2.3 from symfony2.1.7, can not find correct composer.json dependencies?

Tags: php, upgrade, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I am trying to upgrade from Symfony2.1.7 to Symfony2.3 stable release. I am using `php composer.phar update` But I am facing package dependency problems. Below is link to my composer.json and the command line output.

[composer.json](https://gist.github.com/deepak-kumar/5785254)  And [command line output](https://gist.github.com/deepak-kumar/5785258)

After looking at the output I can see friendsofsymfony/user-bundle dependency

```
friendsofsymfony/user-bundle 2.0.x-dev requires symfony/security-bundle >=2.1,<2.3-dev
```

And something similar for sonata-project/user-bundle

```
- symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.3.x-dev requires sonata-project/user-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[dev-master].
- sonata-project/user-bundle dev-master requires friendsofsymfony/user-bundle 1.3.* -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[1.3.x-dev, v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.3.2].
- sonata-project/user-bundle dev-master requires friendsofsymfony/user-bundle 1.3.* -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[1.3.x-dev, v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.3.2].
```

So seems it needs `symfony/security-bundle >=2.1,<2.3-dev` but I want it to be 2.3 or above is it like I can not upgrade with these bundle.

Can someone guide me in right direction, If I am missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my complete composer.json which works with `Symfony version 2.3.2-DEV - app/dev/debug`

```
{
  "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
  "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "": "src/"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*@dev",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",

    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "dev-master",

    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",

    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.5.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",

    "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev",

    "mlehner/gelf-php": "v1.0",

    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.1.*@dev",
    "sensiolabs/doctrine-query-statistics-bundle": "1.0.*@dev",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.9.x",

    "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "1.8.*@dev",

    "sonata-project/exporter": "1.1.*",

    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",

    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "2.1.*@dev",


    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",

    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",

    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master",

    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/markitup-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "dev-master",

    "sonata-project/doctrine-extensions": "1.0.0",

    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.*@dev",

    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",

    "liip/monitor": "0.5.*@dev",
    "liip/monitor-bundle": "0.5.*@dev",

    "mockery/mockery": "0.7.2",

    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.0.3",

    "zendframework/zend-barcode": "2.0.*",
    "zendframework/zend-validator": "2.0.*",

    "egulias/listeners-debug-command-bundle": "*",

    "kylecannon/easycsv": "dev-master",
    "predis/predis": "0.8.*@dev"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
      "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "2.2-dev",
      "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
  }
}
```